# Can't get width of image with Jquery after using max-height for resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-resizing

I have a set of images that I get dynamically. To each image I'm applying a max-height, I use this for re-sizing purposes.

**I have a jquery re-size function:**

// resize my pics

```
function resizeMyImg(objct, containerWidth, containerHeight) {
   var width   = $(objct).width();   // I try alerting here and get a 0 answer
   if (width < containerWidth) {
       var percentageToAdd = ((100 * width) / containerWidth) + 100;
       $(objct).css({ maxHeight: percentageToAdd + "%" });
   }
}
```

**And I'm trying to apply this resize function to my images:**

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $(".photoAlbum").find("img").each(function () {
        var myImage2 = $(this);
        myImage2.load(function () {
            alert(myImage2.height());   // I try alerting here and also get a 0 answer
            resizeMyImg(myImage2, 240, 240);
        });
    });
});
```

**This is the html I'm using in my page, hope it helps:**

```
<div style="padding-top: 0px;" id="photosHere">

                    <div class="photoAlbum">

                        <img alt="" src="/Uploads/553290_471992686161625_498413822_n867.jpg" style="max-height: 100%;">

                    </div>

                    <div class="photoAlbum">

                        <img alt="" src="/Uploads/484524_430827793626240_991120671_n575.jpg" style="max-height: 100%;">

                    </div>

                    <div class="photoAlbum">

                        <img alt="" src="/Uploads/553290_471992686161625_498413822_n717.jpg" style="max-height: 100%;">

                    </div>

                    <div class="photoAlbum">

                        <img alt="" src="/Uploads/me993.jpg" style="max-height: 100%;">

                    </div>

                    <div class="photoAlbum">

                        <img alt="" src="/Uploads/me759.jpg" style="max-height: 100%;">

                    </div>

                </div>
```

My problem is that I can't get the width of the images I always get a 0 instead of the real width. However, using firebug if I test an image I get the correct width.

**N.B:** Sometimes I get the correct answer but then I refresh and get 0 again. Any suggestions please ?? It's frustrating I've spent hours on this..

Comment: could you please show me full code of your page i want to know how you pass the function in html or a fiddle if you can let me know

Comment: I've added the HTML which was the only missing part. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3):

Today I was writing a jQuery plugin and I had the same issue so I ended up referencing the DOM element instead. Try

`$(this)[0].height` instead of `myImage2.height()`

and

`$(this)[0].width` instead of `myImage2.width()`.

Comment: You must reference, and be aware-of, the context in which event handlers are invoked. This answer provides the correct solution because load is an event handler, and as are all event-handlers, the context (this) is the DOM object on which the event occurred. And, it is executed in a scope (window) where myImage2 is undefined.

Comment: More imporantly, use the following reference (don't create a jQuery ojected, unless necessary):

this.height instead of myImage2.height()

and

this.width instead of myImage2.width()... remember, this is a DOM object which (in this case, of an Image) possesses the intrinsic attributes, height and width. Don't waste a call to jQuery for this.

Comment: Hi guys, thank you for your feedback.. I've tried using $(this)[0].width and it doesn't give me 0 as value anymore, but it gives me a value different than the actual re-sized width of the image...

Comment: @user1922845 I recommend manipulating the width and height attributes, checking both scales first (that of the image and that of the container) instead of messing with the max-height css rule.

Comment: @inhan Nop. Using max-height and max-width will get you a neat re-size with almost no jquery code at all.. There's just this part missing and I can't seem to be able to figure it out..

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the correct width may be from fiddling in firebug, and a refresh clears all of the fiddling.

Did you try:

```
 alert(myImage2.outerHeight());
```

in your second shown code and

```
var width = $(objct).outerWidth
```

in your first code?
( http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/)

Comment: What does the console say is the metric of the pictures (not console.log, but opening the metric)?  If you had a fiddle or working example, it would be easier to diagnose.  It seems like your code should be solid.

Comment: I've added the HTML I'm using in my question. hope that helps ?
Just a note, after using $(this)[0].height instead of myImage2.height() the outerHeight() works but gives me the original height of the image not the re-sized one. And if I use .height() I get a value different from 0 but still not the height of the re-sized image..